# Check if valid hh:mm format with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm trying to sum time (format `hh:mm`) from table with Moment.js.

**Here is my js:**

```
function timemanage(){
        $('.lebih').each (function() {
            if(moment('.lebih', 'hh:mm').isValid()){
                var value = $(this).text();
                    if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
                    sum += parseFloat(value);
                    }
                    $('.jamlebih').val(sum); 

            }else{
                alert("No");
            }
        });
    }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    timemanage();   
  });
```

**Here is my table:**

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td> No </td>
        <td> Full Name </td>
        <td> Attendance Date </td>
        <td> In Time </td>
        <td> Out Time </td>

        <td> Waktu Lebih </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>[1602744] - RAHMAT </td>
    <td>2016-08-28</td>
    <td class="jammasuk">
        08:55:00                                        
    </td>                                                                           
    <td class="jampulang">
    16:03:00                                        
    </td>
    <td class="lebih">Jam Kerja Kurang Dari 8 Jam</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>[1602744] - RAHMAT </td>
    <td>2016-08-29</td>
    <td class="jammasuk">
        08:55:00                                        
    </td>                                                                           
    <td class="jampulang">
    16:03:00                                       
     </td>
    <td class="lebih">Jam Kerja Kurang Dari 8 Jam</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>[1602744] - RAHMAT </td>
    <td>2016-08-30</td>
    <td class="jammasuk">
    08:55:00                                        
    </td>                                                                           
    <td class="jampulang">
    16:03:00                                        
    </td>
    <td class="lebih">Jam Kerja Kurang Dari 8 Jam</td>

    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>[1602744] - RAHMAT </td>
    <td>2016-08-31</td>
    <td class="jammasuk">
        08:55:00                                        
    </td>                                                                           
    <td class="jampulang">
    18:03:00                                        
    </td>
    <td class="lebih">01:08</td>

    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="4"> </td>
        <td>Total Jam Lebih</td>
         <td>
         <input name="jamlebih" type="text" readonly disabled class="jmljam" />

         </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="4"> </td>
        <td>Ro Yang DiDapatkan</td>
         <td>
         <input name="dapetro" type="text" readonly disabled class="ronya" />
         </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

I have read the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/guides/) but I can't see any part on how to check if the format `hh:mm` is valid. With my script above I always receive alert `no`.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s9wfh9ye/3/).

Comment: I don't see any `hh:mm` in your table, only `hh:mm:ss` - and the `'.lebih'` elements that you are selecting don't contain a time at all. (Also, I'm not very familiar with moment.js, but I imagine `moment('.lebih', 'hh:mm')` should be `moment($(this).text(), 'hh:mm')`, and you would need to use the value produced by moment.js in your sum - you're using the original text.)

Comment: @nnnnnn That's the problem in `lebih`. For some condition there are a text showing up. So i try to use `isValid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand the text on your page, but I have done my best with your explanation. Here is my version: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s9wfh9ye/5/) Please note I also changed one of the time boxes for testing purposes to add two values together.

As explained in the comments on your post, you need to give momentjs a value to parse from, that being `$(this).text()`. But momentjs is very forgiving in parsing. It will still parse the '8' out of your text. So you have to initialize your moment with 'true' as the third argument, like so: `var thisMoment = moment(value, 'hh:mm', true);`. This enables strict parsing, so moment will not parse the '8'.

It is also a decent idea to use moment's built-in `.add(object)` to add two moments together. Since we are only using `hh:mm`, I do `var total = moment().startOf('day')` to give us a clean slate of `12:00:00` to add to.

You were also trying to change the value of a class that didn't exist. You have `$('.jamlebih').val(sum);` when you actually want to get it via the input name (Or you can add the class yourself, if you want.) like so: `$("input[name='jamlebih']")`

Comment: You helping me. I missed this part when read documentation `http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/`

Comment: I should also point out that I realized that this will not add above 12. If this is not a limitation you can work with, you could have it add up to 24, or change the code to include days or even weeks, and then print out how many days/weeks it adds up to.